# Finding a neighborhhod basis of a specific topological space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ any set.

Let $T_f$ the cofinite topology ($T_f:=\{U\subset X , X\setminus U\text{ is finite}\} \cup \{ \emptyset\}$)

I am looking for a neighborhood basis of the topological space $(X, T_f)$

(Definition of a neighborhood basis:  Let $(X, T)$ be a topological space and $B_x$ a family of neighborhoods of $x \in X$. $B_x$ is called a basis of neighborhood at $x \in X$ if for all neighborhood of x, $\exists B \in B_x$ s.t $B\in N$)

Now I found neighborhood basis for other topological spaces but I am having trouble with this specific one.

**EDIT** $B_x$ has to be different than $\{U\in\tau_f:x\in U\}$

Comment: Just let $\mathscr{B}_x=\{U\in\tau_f:x\in U\}$; there really isn’t anything simpler.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to specify that $\mathscr{B}_x \neq \{U\in\tau_f:x\in U\}$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $X$ is infinite, let $\mathscr{B}_x=\{U\in\tau:x\in U\text{ and }|X\setminus U|\ge 2\}$. If $X$ is finite, let $\mathscr{B}_x=\big\{\{x\}\big\}$.